# Prenatal testing

Tags: halacha, women, medicine, pregnancy-birth, inspection

I've been hearing that some people are discouraging prenatal testing for halachic reasons but it seems pretty important to me.

Does anyone know if there's actually something halachicly wrong about doing these tests?

Comment: What kind of testing?  Genetic diseases?  Sex?  Paternity?

Comment: Milky Weinberg, welcome to Judaism.SE, and thanks very much for bringing this interesting question here! Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Comment: Remember to consult your local Rabbi before doing anything based on any answer you receive here.

Comment: Hmm. Related? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2836/sonogram-ultrasonography-on-infant-for-gender

Comment: @Shmuelbrin Remember to consult your Doctor, too!

Answer (score 4):

See [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/11926/21). Those rabbis who prohibit aborting a fetus even if it has Downs, Tay-Sachs, or the like, strongly frown upon testing for such things if there's nothing you can do about it -- or you'll put yourself in a situation where it will take superhuman strength to follow halacha.